# sed: move matched lines to after a pattern?

Tags: awk, sed

I have a `.drone.yml` config file:

```
workspace:
  base: x
  path: y

pipeline:
  import-groups-check:
    pull: true

  static-check:
    pull: true

  build:
    image: golang:1.9.0

  publish:
    image: plugins/docker:1.13

  validate-merge-request:
    pull: true

  notify-youtrack:
    pull: true
```

What I want is move the `validate-merge-request` to be the first step:

```
workspace:
  base: x
  path: y

pipeline:
  validate-merge-request:
    pull: true

  import-groups-check:
    pull: true

  static-check:
    pull: true

  build:
    image: golang:1.9.0

  publish:
    image: plugins/docker:1.13

  notify-youtrack:
    pull: true
```

I know that we can use something like this to extract the `validate-merge-request` step:

```
sed -e '/validate-merge-request/,/^ *$/!{H;d;}'
```

How can I move this to after the `pipeline:`?

Answer (score 2):

POSIXLY:

```
sed -e '
  # From first line to pipeline:,just print and start next cycle
  1,/^pipeline:$/b
  # With all lines outside validate-merge-request block, push to hold space,
  # delete them and start next cycle
  # On last line, exchange hold space to pattern space, print pattern space
  /validate-merge-request/,/^$/!{
    H
    ${
      x
      s/\n//
      p
    }
    d
  }' <file
```

Note that all lines after `pipeline:` and not in `validate-merge-request` block will be kept in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Mappings are inherently unordered. If you want the pipeline data to be ordered, you need a sequence:

```
workspace:
  base: x
  path: y
pipeline:
- import-groups-check:
    pull: true
- static-check:
    pull: true
- build:
    image: golang:1.9.0
- publish:
    image: plugins/docker:1.13
- validate-merge-request:
    pull: true
- notify-youtrack:
    pull: true
```

Obviously this will affect how you're currently processing that YAML file.

If you make that change, you can do something like this:

```
ruby -e '
  require "yaml"
  data = YAML.load(File.read ARGV.shift)
  idx = data["pipeline"].find_index {|elem| elem.has_key? "validate-merge-request"}
  data["pipeline"].unshift( data["pipeline"].delete_at idx )    
  puts YAML.dump(data)
' .drone.yml
```

which outputs

```
---
workspace:
  base: x
  path: y
pipeline:
- validate-merge-request:
    pull: true
- import-groups-check:
    pull: true
- static-check:
    pull: true
- build:
    image: golang:1.9.0
- publish:
    image: plugins/docker:1.13
- notify-youtrack:
    pull: true
```

Comment: I won't vote on this only because I don't know enough about YAML to ascertain its accuracy, but very good on addressing the underlying assumptions instead of answering a potentially wrong question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `ed`:

```
ed -s file >/dev/null <<ED_END
/validate-merge-request:/
.,+2m/pipeline:/
wq
ED_END
```

The `ed` editing script will first search for the line containing the string `validate-merge-request:`.  It then moves this line and the two immediately following lines to after the line containing `pipeline:`.  The file is then saved under the same name and the script exits.

To move the lines from the line matching `validate-merge-request:` to the next blank line, use `/^$/` in place of `+2`.

The script makes the change in place, so be careful.  To write to a new file, use

```
ed -s file >/dev/null <<ED_END
/validate-merge-request:/
.,+2m/pipeline:/
w file-new
ED_END
```

This would write the modified document to `file-new`.

Comment: "and the two immediately following lines" -> No, it needed to be the next blank line. How can I do that?

Comment: @quanta then make that : `.,/^$/m/pipeline:/`

Comment: @quanta Exactly.